# How to display full map without world repeat and add infinite ocean using mapbox-gl?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Is it possible to display the entire map using mapbox-gl library without repeating the world and instead add an infinite ocean? And if yes, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to achieve that.